# How to select a row in a single insert query after it is inserted, in sql?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I need a query that will insert into "TABLE-A" select from "TABLE-A" and will loop.

Assume "TABLE-A" has 1 row and the query will continue inserting unless it reaches 99 copying the same row

I Tried

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE-A` (columns,columns....)
SELECT (columns,columns....) FROM `TABLE-A` WHERE id<100
```

Comment: What do you mean with "loop"?

Comment: your query will insert all rows that you selected

Comment: Assume it has 1 row and it'll continue inserting unless it reaches 99 copying the same row

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you ultimately trying to achieve? If you have just inserted the data why do you want to select it again?

Comment: I have a query that will insert rows depending on the value it inserted in the same query

Comment: Please add your DBMS tag. Generation of arbitrary number of rows is very specific

Comment: t-sql is a declarative language, not a procedural language. Meaning that a statement like the one above will not loop, looping is a procedure construct. Although there are ways to write procedural sql that is usually platform dependent and not needed in most cases.

Comment: Can you please help me out with a possible way to do it?